# winbind and passwd issues

Tags: samba, pam, passwd, kerberos

I successfully configured a Ubuntu 15.10 Workstation to authenticate against Active Directory. The only thing left so far is the ability to change the Active Directory password. When I enter the command `passwd` as logged in Active Directory User I see the following:

**Case 1:**

```
aduser@xenomorph:~$ passwd
Changing password for aduser
(current) NT password: 
passwd: Permission denied
passwd: password unchanged
```

**Case 2:**

```
aduser@xenomorph:~$ passwd aduser
Changing password for aduser
(current) NT password: 
passwd: Permission denied
passwd: password unchanged
```

**Case 3:**

```
aduser@xenomorph:~$ passwd DOMAIN\\aduser
Changing password for DOMAIN\aduser
(current) NT password: 
passwd: Permission denied
passwd: password unchanged
```

In all three situations I receive the following logs (The user name changes but the errors are the same):

```
Nov 19 12:58:59 xenomorph passwd[5691]: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): user "aduser" does not exist in /etc/passwd
Nov 19 12:58:59 xenomorph passwd[5691]: pam_winbind(passwd:chauthtok): getting password (0x0000002a)
Nov 19 12:59:03 xenomorph passwd[5691]: pam_winbind(passwd:chauthtok): user 'aduser' granted access
Nov 19 12:59:03 xenomorph passwd[5691]: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): user "aduser" does not exist in /etc/passwd
Nov 19 12:59:03 xenomorph passwd[5691]: pam_winbind(passwd:chauthtok): getting password (0x00000012)
```

my `pam.d` file: `common-password` looks like this one (I removed all comments for better readability):

```
password [success=2 default=ignore] pam_unix.so obscure use_authtok try_first_pass sha512
password [success=1 default=ignore] pam_winbind.so use_authtok try_first_pass
password requisite pam_deny.so
password required pam_permit.so
password optional pam_gnome_keyring.so
```

I don't have any clue how to solve the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Not relevant for answering your question: what guide/procedure did you follow to authenticate against AD? Can you give a link?

Comment: Here you go...http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linuxquestions-org-member-success-stories-23/%5Btutorial%5D-ad-integration-with-ubuntu-14-04-and-winbind-4175516531/