# How to join Ubuntu 15.04 / 15.10 to Windows domain

Tags: 15.10, domain-server, join

Could you help me with Ubuntu 15.04 or 15.10 Desktop in join a windows server 2008/2012 domain.

I have tried google this problem but none of them work.

I was not able to get likewise an `powerbroker` to work.

I am very new at Linux Ubuntu I need all the help I can get to do this, Ubuntu 15.04/15.10 Desktop PC to join a windows server 2008 domain and be able to login with AD and map network drives from the window server. Can anyone help?

Comment: what problem do you experienced with likewise/powerbroker?

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/700535/winbind-and-passwd-issues, in comment https://askubuntu.com/questions/700535/winbind-and-passwd-issues#comment1028956_700535 you may find the pointer to a helpful tutorial.

Comment: likewise/powerbroker failed installed on 15.04/15.10 and tired to allow AD users login into ubuntu